# Can I use regular 5/8" thick drywall in a 1/2 bath (powder room)?

Tags: bathroom, drywall

Can I use regular 5/8" thick drywall in a 1/2 bath (powder room)?

It's a very small room, with just a toilet and a sink to wash one's hands.
My dad has a bunch of excess regular drywall panels (5/8" thick)
Since there is not tub or shower, is it OK or not advised?

Comment: You should be fine since you will not have a moisture issue like you would in a full bath.

Comment: It's fine, even in a full bath. Modern drywall sealers and paints make the need for greenboard obsolete. Be aware, though, that thicker drywall can create door and electrical trim hassles. One wall is not so much of a problem, but if you do both sides your door jambs are now 1/4" too narrow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can use the 5/8" drywall, plus you will get the added benefit of better sound barrier and fire rating.